# How to redirect Autodiscover away from Apache?

Tags: apache, redirect, outlook, office365

I am trying to redirect the Autodiscover.xml for Outlook away from our web server as we do not host our Exchange locally, we use office365.

After much reading, I believe I am close, though when testing yesterday, it redirects didn't appear to work.

**Question:**
I am wondering if there is something wrong with the configurations that I am using? Am I missing a configuration to have this work properly?

Contents of my `.htaccess` file from `/var/www/html/public/`

```
SetEnv HTTPS on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
Options - Autodiscover
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ autodiscover.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Contents of the `autodiscover.php` file.

```
    <?php
preg_match("/\<EMailAddress\>(.*?)\<\/EMailAddress\>/", $data, $matches);

//set Content-Type
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'; ?>
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
<Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
<Account>
<AccountType>email</AccountType>
<Action>settings</Action>
<Protocol>
<Type>POP3</Type>
<Server>mail.plym.com</Server>
<Port>995</Port>
<LoginName><?php echo $matches[1]; ?></LoginName>
<DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
<DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
</Protocol>
<Protocol>
<Type>IMAP</Type>
<Server>mail.plym.com</Server>
<Port>993</Port>
<DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
<LoginName><?php echo $matches[1]; ?></LoginName>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
</Protocol>
<Protocol>
<Type>SMTP</Type>
<Server>mail.plym.com</Server>
<Port>465</Port>
<DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
<LoginName><?php echo $matches[1]; ?></LoginName>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
<UsePOPAuth>on</UsePOPAuth>
<SMTPLast>off</SMTPLast>
</Protocol>
</Account>
</Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

As I stated above, I want to know if there is something wrong with my configuration for this to work properly? Thank you for any and all assistance with this one!

Comment: If this fails to meet any of the formatting rules, or the content is not clear, please let me know and I will do my best to correct them or make things more clear. Thanks again!